# Bars disappear when I add geom_text() to show label on the bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

This is my code and when I add the last line of code, which is geom_text() to add labels on the bars, my bars disappears. Moreover, this happens in geom_bar(position="fill") but not in geom_bar(position="stack"). Couldn't find out the reason. My graph is a circular bar graph. Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.
This is my data

```
structure(list(Corporations = c("Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", 
"Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", "Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", 
"Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", "Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", 
"Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", "Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", 
"Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", "Nichtfinanzielle Kapitalgesellschaften", 
"Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", "Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", 
"Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", "Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", 
"Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", "Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", 
"Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", "Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", 
"Finanzielle Kapitalgellschaften", "Private Haushalte", "Private Haushalte", 
"Private Haushalte", "Private Haushalte", "Private Haushalte", 
"Private Haushalte", "Private Haushalte", "Private Haushalte", 
"Private Haushalte", "Staat", "Staat", "Staat", "Staat", "Staat", 
"Staat", "Staat", "Staat", "Staat", "Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", 
"Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", "Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", 
"Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", "Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", 
"Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", "Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", 
"Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck", "Private Organisationen ohne Erwerbszweck"
), Instruments = c("Währungsgold und Sonderziehungsrechte", "Bargeld", 
"Einlagen", "Schuldverschreibungen", "Kredite", "Anteilsrechte", 
"Versicherungstechnische Rückstellungen", "Finanzderivate und Mitarbeiteroptionen", 
"Sonstige Forderungen", "Währungsgold und Sonderziehungsrechte", 
"Bargeld", "Einlagen", "Schuldverschreibungen", "Kredite", "Anteilsrechte", 
"Versicherungstechnische Rückstellungen", "Finanzderivate und Mitarbeiteroptionen", 
"Sonstige Forderungen", "Währungsgold und Sonderziehungsrechte", 
"Bargeld", "Einlagen", "Schuldverschreibungen", "Kredite", "Anteilsrechte", 
"Versicherungstechnische Rückstellungen", "Finanzderivate und Mitarbeiteroptionen", 
"Sonstige Forderungen", "Währungsgold und Sonderziehungsrechte", 
"Bargeld", "Einlagen", "Schuldverschreibungen", "Kredite", "Anteilsrechte", 
"Versicherungstechnische Rückstellungen", "Finanzderivate und Mitarbeiteroptionen", 
"Sonstige Forderungen", "Währungsgold und Sonderziehungsrechte", 
"Bargeld", "Einlagen", "Schuldverschreibungen", "Kredite", "Anteilsrechte", 
"Versicherungstechnische Rückstellungen", "Finanzderivate und Mitarbeiteroptionen", 
"Sonstige Forderungen"), Q1.19 = c(NA, 6299, 555223, 2427, 32995, 
2189603, 56996, 31362, 1198580, 139931, 38424, 4340085, 3202446, 
60692, 2975850, 89437, 588297, 342623, NA, 230878, 2251130, 12242, 
1625426, 1255442, 2281472, 0, 30619, NA, 487, 319099, 6259, 38429, 
617751, 948, 41669, 99347, NA, NA, 62271, 1840, 15811, 92797, 
NA, 422, NA), Q2.19 = c(NA, 6454, 551837, 2085, 31926, 2198338, 
57709, 32616, 1178917, 148943, 39256, 4359950, 3303698, 60708, 
3056242, 89612, 726303, 358358, NA, 239382, 2284960, 12250, 1645940, 
1292362, 2297914, 0, 31502, NA, 487, 330817, 6150, 39239, 645949, 
954, -41925, 94741, NA, NA, 62626, 1839, 15866, 95467, NA, 362, 
NA), Q3.19 = c(NA, 6466, 573901, 2295, 32219, 2232079, 58430, 
32051, 1203447, 162442, 39311, 4261998, 3420453, 60885, 3157147, 
91016, 920818, 382937, NA, 249723, 2298254, 12225, 1667098, 1322047, 
2313450, 0, 32251, NA, 487, 330779, 6004, 42480, 676359, 960, 
-47370, 108842, NA, NA, 62854, 1913, 16052, 98454, NA, 480, NA
), Q4.19 = c(NA, 7386, 590593, 2183, 33011, 2317831, 59160, 31542, 
1229358, 161204, 44712, 4089901, 3332533, 60485, 3266643, 91257, 
761489, 440720, NA, 260243, 2337146, 12045, 1686127, 1383188, 
2331436, 0, 32043, NA, 487, 313552, 5315, 40097, 670891, 966, 
-42715, 104839, NA, NA, 61959, 1919, 16446, 103620, NA, 380, 
NA), Q1.20 = c(NA, 6742, 588896, 1979, 33086, 2103282, 59900, 
44907, 1178927, 173489, 49423, 4494126, 3354457, 61080, 2975370, 
90025, 1102066, 400057, NA, 279788, 2341738, 10748, 1703401, 
1220313, 2354882, 0, 31439, NA, 487, 350979, 5709, 41296, 664676, 
972, -44212, 115474, NA, NA, 62339, 1740, 16510, 94113, NA, 412, 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

This is my code;

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Corporations, y = Q1.19, fill = Instruments)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar() +
  ggtitle(expression(paste(underline("Quartal 1, 2019")))) +
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(color="red", size=2),
        legend.box.margin = margin(16, 6, 6, 6),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = wrap_format(10)) +
  geom_text(aes(y=Q1.19, label = paste(Q1.19)), 
            size = 2, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.7))
```

Comment: Hi Ravi. Could you add the contents of `data` in your question to help us debug? Just type `dput(data)` in R and paste the result into a new code block in your question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Allan. I've added the data now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below. I changed `position_stack` in `geom_text` to `position_fill`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Corporations, y = Q1.19, fill = Instruments)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar() +
  ggtitle(expression(paste(underline("Quartal 1, 2019")))) +
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(color="red", size=2),
        legend.box.margin = margin(16, 6, 6, 6),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = wrap_format(10)) +
  geom_text(aes(y=Q1.19, label = paste(Q1.19)), 
            size = 2, position = position_fill(vjust = 0.7))
```

Comment: Can you please explain why the change works? For me, position_fill is not an option, so I can't learn from this solution.